# MySQL Data show by php. If select show selected data, If no select; show whole data. How can I do this?

Tags: php, mysql, select, show

This is a blood donation web site. If anybody want to see his areas donor; he select blood-grp, district and area. But if he do not select area field, He see nothing. But I want He see whole districts donor. How can I do this? Here is my code

```
$blood-grp=$_POST['blood-grp']; 
$district=$_POST['district']; 
$area=$_POST['area']; 


$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE blood-grp='$blood-grp' && district='$district' && area='$area'";
```

Comment: Do a quick search on SQL Injection. If you're directly passing user entered information into SQL queries generally, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: Oh dear. The three answers below all replicate the SQL injection bug, which will get you hacked pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this you will get sure

if he doesn't select his area then if user has registration then take the user are else going with latitude and longitude

```
 if($_POST['area']=="")
 {
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE blood-grp='$blood-grp' AND  area='$userarea'";
 } else {
  $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE blood-grp='$blood-grp' AND district='$district' AND area='$area'";

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `if` to check if it was set. And side note: hyphen (`-` ) isn't allowed in variable names

```
$blood_grp=$_POST['blood-grp'];
$area=$_POST['area'];

if (isset($_POST['district'])) {
  $district=$_POST['district']; 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE `blood-grp`='$blood_grp' AND district='$district' AND area='$area'";
} else {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE `blood-grp`='$blood_grp' AND area='$area'";
}
```

Comment: yes its still possible having hyphenated variable names: `${'test-var'} = 'test';`. It just sucks so don't use it. and hyphenated columns names should be wrapped with backticks

Comment: yeah, forgot about MySQL. Corrected. And yes, I know `${'some-name'}` but it's just so weird and unnatural that I prefer to not even mention it. But still, PHP Manual itself states that variable names can use only alphanumerical characters (with some national utf-8 chars too which was shock for me) and underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write down your query more structured using concatination and if.
This way only parameters that were selected by the user are actually imlpemented in your query.

And "-" character is not allowed in variable names thatshwy I corrected that to "_".

```
$blood_grp=$_POST['blood_grp']; 
$district=$_POST['district']; 
$area=$_POST['area']; 


$sql="SELECT * 
      FROM $tbl_name
      WHERE ";

if(strlen($blood-grp) > 0) {
    $query .= "blood_grp = '$blood_grp' AND ";
}
if(strlen($district) > 0) {
    $query .= "district = '$district' AND ";
}

if(strlen($area) > 0) {
    $query .= "area = '$area' AND ";
}

//Remove final " AND " by cutting off last 5 characters to make the query valid:
$query = substr($query, 0, strlen($query) - 5);

echo $query;
```

Comment: Actually `$query = substr($query, 0, -4);` will work as well and even better. Also, it's better to try `!empty(...)` than `strlen(...) > 0`